# Cómo puedo acceder al LocalStorage desde Java en Android Studio?

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, cordova

Estoy desarrollando una `app` usando `cordova` con `html`, `css`, `js` y el servicio `rest` con `php`. La `app` actualiza la ubicación del usuario cada cierto tiempo, esta función funciona correctamente cuando la aplicación está abierta y también en segundo plano, el problema es cuando la aplicación se cierra completamente, estaba investigando que puedo usar `servicios` en java pero este servicio solo se puede ejecutar con el lenguaje nativo es por eso que necesito unos datos que almaceno en el `localStorage` con `js` para crear un servicio que actualice la ubicación del usuario cuando la `app` esté completamente cerrada.

Si conocen otra forma u otra solución para el mismo problema sin necesidad de usar `servicios` de java en `android` también es bienvenido.

Desde ya muchas gracias!